# null is not an Object. RNGestureHandlerModule-Direction

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a react native application. All of a sudden i start getting this error. I didnt change any of the files in react-navigation.  Why does this error come even if i dont change anything in the App.js or any Navigation files,

Comment: try `react-native link react-native-gesture-handler`, and if still doesn't work, try manual linking instead

Comment: I did that. It works sometimes. But it would really help if you could tell me the reason for the problem. Why does it gets automatically unlinked?

Comment: it's not that it gets automatically unlinked, but sometimes, by running `react-native link` instead of `react-native link dependecy-name`, will not linked the package fully

Comment: Did you get the error on Android, iOS or both of them?

Answer (score 3):

The install/uninstall solution didn't work for me.
I fixed this issue with just a "`pod install`" in ios project (I thought that RNGestureHandler was already installed but no it wasn't, I don't know why).
After that I was able to run my project in the ios simulator.

[image]

Comment: Can you share your podfile ?

Comment: You don't have to touch/modify yourself your podfile. 
I can't send my podfile here it's too long.

Comment: The commands in the terminal I needed were:

cd ios

pod install

Answer (score 2):

If Linking is not working, then you should do this (for me worked):

1. Unlink Handler Gesture
2. Uninstall react-navigation-gesture-handler
3. Uninstall react-navigation

> react-native unlink react-native-gesture-handler
>
> npm uninstall react-navigation
>
> npm uninstall react-navigation-gesture-handler

Than, follow these steps:

> npm install --save react-navigation
>
> npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler
>
> react-native link react-native-gesture-handler

What i did wrong, is that i didn't '--save' Gesture Handler.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the react-native-gesture-handler and then link it.

Comment: I did that. It works sometimes. But it would really help if you could tell me the reason for the problem. Why does it gets automatically unlinked?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, first I closed the app in the simulator and then and rebuild the app with react-native run-ios command and error message is gone away.